# XHR response to Json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xmlhttprequest

I'm writing a chrome extension for a specific site [Lernu.net](http://en.lernu.net/komunikado/forumo/temo.php?t=18468) that generates a new DOM element when the user clicks on a word.

The new div DOM contains the translation of a word with an id of "v0", and a new one is generated every time a user clicks on a word

Here's what the div looks like:

```
<div class="vortarobobelo" id="bobelo0.889891296857968" title="Duoble alklaku por reteni la slipeton." style="z-index: 10000000; display: block; width: 20em; top: 410px; visibility: visible; left: 391px;">
<div class="superbiblenhavo">
    <div class="vorto" id="v0">
        <h3>
            <strong>malbono</strong> (mal·bon·o ← bon·a)
        </h3>
        <div id="en25964">evil, bad</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="fermilo1" onclick="this.parentNode.gepatro.superbibl = 0; ForigiBobelon(this.parentNode);">X</div>
<div class="fermilo2" onclick="this.parentNode.gepatro.superbibl = 0; ForigiBobelon(this.parentNode);">X</div>
<div class="fermilo3" onclick="this.parentNode.gepatro.superbibl = 0; ForigiBobelon(this.parentNode);">X</div>
<div class="fermilo4" onclick="this.parentNode.gepatro.superbibl = 0; ForigiBobelon(this.parentNode);">X</div>
```

Here's what I have for the javascript

```
document.onclick = get_content() 

function get_content(){

var element = document.getElementById("v0"); // gets <div id="v0" and assign to var element
var text = element.innerText || element.textContent; /* gets the text in div. the || serves as optional argument
                                                        then the second arugment is evaluted */
console.log(text);

return text;
};
```

I got two problems:

1. The function is automatically triggered upon the loading of the webpage, but I only want it to run when the user clicks on a variable with the the css tag 
style="cursor:help;"

2. I get a XHR responds from the function but what I really want is a json object containing the word and the translation.

```
XHR finished loading: GET "http://en.lernu.net/cgi-bin/serchi.pl?modelo=malbonon&delingvo=eo&allingvo=…=0&starto=0&bobeloid=bobelo0.889891296857968&dishaki=true&hazardo=bNL4XQNJ".
```

I can see in the console log that it returns a response, but I can only see it in the console under the netword tab. 
Typing in "text" in console returns undefined, so does get_content().

Comment: what XHR? Need to remove `()` from `document.onclick = get_content()`. You are invoking the function not assigning  reference to it

Comment: I get 
    XHR finished loading: GET "http://en.lernu.net/cgi-bin/serchi.pl?modelo=Religiaj&delingvo=eo&allingvo=…=0&starto=0&bobeloid=bobelo0.473883792757988&dishaki=true&hazardo=kzVzELdy".   as a response in my console

Comment: but that's a url...not a response. You are going to need to provide considerably more detail if you want help

Comment: When I create the function in the console of the webpage, it returns a string just fine. However, when I package it as an chrome extension it gives the url instead

Comment: That doesn't make sense...where's the code...update the question

Comment: ok, I just update the question, thanks for your patience btw